# Do I really need to configure each subfolder in my Exchange inbox for push on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-mail

I have an iPhone 5 running iOS 7. I have an Exchange inbox with at least a dozen subfolders and server-side rules that "pre-sort" mail to these subfolders. If I want to receive push notifications for these subfolders (and I do), I have to configure this for every single subfolder. When I add new folders in Outlook, I need to remember to add it on my phone.

Is there a way to tell the iOS mail client to push *all* subfolders of a given inbox automatically?

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears to be no, and it is a longstanding issue.
http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1868
https://discussions.apple.com/message/23132172#23132172
https://discussions.apple.com/message/8516130#8516130

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the native mail app yes you can do this in IOS. In Settings > mail,contacts, calendars > fetch new data > Exchange is a list of all folders and only inbox will be checked for pushed folders. Select the folders you want auto pushed and you should be all set.

Comment: Read the question again.